# How to echo out a the first name name in my array if associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php 

        $players = [
            
            [
                'name' => 'ronaldo',
                'quality' => 'best plaeyr'
            ],

            [
                'name' => 'scholes',
                'quality' => 'respected'
            ],

            [
                'name' => 'mbaape',
                'quality' => 'fastest'
            ]
        ];
    ?>
```

this is my $players array
This is how i printed out the list of names

```
<?php foreach ($players as $player) : ?>
    <li> <?= $player['name']?> </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

this works well, but how do i echo out like the first name in the list, like `ronaldo` specifically and not all the names like in the loop above.

tried this

```
<?php foreach ($players as $player) : ?>
      
    <?php 
    
    if($players[0])
    {
        echo $player['name'];  
    }; 
    
    ?>
```

but this just prints out all 3 names not just the first one that i need i.e. `ronaldo`.

Comment: `echo $players[0]['name'];` (no loop required)

Comment: As a side note, the correct spelling is "mbappé", not "mbaape".

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do that:

- Stop the loop after the first run.
- Print the first name directly without using a loop.
- Consider using the `reset` function as suggested by `nice_dev`.

**Stopping Loop**

```
foreach ($players as $player)
{
    echo $player['name'];
    break;
}
```

**Printing first name directy**

```
echo $players[0]['name'];
```

Comment: thank you so much I was doing this  - echo $player[0]['name']; instead of this - echo $players[0]['name'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) for this. It works for associative array as well.

```
<?php

echo reset($players)['name'];
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/op4Lc)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop you could just check whether `$players` is indeed an array and has element, in which case you can echo the name of the 0'th item.

```
<?php if( is_array( $players ) && 0 < count( $players ) ) { echo $players[0]['name']; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop with an index:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($players); $index++) {
    if ($index === 0) echo $players[$index]["name"];
}
```

If you only really need the first element, then you do not need a loop at all, you're fine by just referring the name of the 0'th element, like `$players[0]["name"]`. But it's good to know that there is a way to conditionally do something in the loop for cases that actually require a loop, like echoing paired indexed elements or so.